# How can I get Chef to error or at least report a missing variable in an .erb template?

Tags: chef-infra, erb, chef-recipe, chef-template

If I have a line like the below in an .erb:

```
        TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d <%= @temp_dir %>/tmp_dir.XXXXXX)
```

Is there a way I can get Chef to fail, or at least report, if the @temp_dir variable is undefined?

Ideally I'd like to do this with a single call at the top of the recipe, or at the command line with a config option (I'm using chef-client).

Thanks ahead!

Comment: It looks like Puppet has this functionality: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/configuration.html#strictvariables ...

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error and exit Chef with:

`Chef::Application.fatal!("Temporary directory is undefined") unless defined? temp_dir`

It will not cover empty variable, so you might add `temp_dir.empty?` check or whatever applies to your case

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really looking to trigger some sort of strict behavior where no undefined variable use is permitted.  I'd like to apply this not only to one variable, but to a mature project with well over 100 templates, and likely thousands of variables, and I can't think of a single use case where an undefined variable should be OK.